# installing GeoDjango on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, geodjango

I am trying to build a webapp which uses GeoDjango. The app is to be hosted on Heroku, but I am facing issues in it. I am using [this](https://github.com/dulaccc/heroku-buildpack-geodjango) buildpack but then this [error](https://github.com/dulaccc/heroku-buildpack-geodjango/issues/4) is coming. Figured out that this is happening because of Cedar 14 but I am not clear as to what should I do next.

Also I tried using [this](https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack) buildpack but as discussed [here](https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack/issues/22), this issue can be resolved by using the buildpath as

`$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git#1.3`

I tried the same but now it is not detecting it as a Python app and now I am facing the issue of "**django import error - No module named core.management** " missing, which is because its not installing Django.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this problem myself only.

To add multiple values for a `BUILDPACK_URL`, one needs to use a buildpack which can add support for mutiple `BUILDPACK_URL`.

So I used [this](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi). One can write like

`$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`

After this create a file `.buildpacks` and add to it the following

`https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git#e1b845b
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git`

Note that `#e1845b` is because of [this](https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack/issues/22#issuecomment-66656881) comment, which mentions that it is because of some caching issues.