# Problems deploying GeoDjango application on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, geodjango

I'm having troubles to deploy my GeoDjango application on heroku (using Free Dyno but I'm able to change if necessary). When I execute `push heroku master --force` I got the following error:

```
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
            'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
        Error was: cannot import name 'GDALRaster'
```

I already installed postgis:

```
$ heroku pg:psql
create extension postgis;
```

Configured buildpacks:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git

Created .buildpacks file at my project with this links:

https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git#1.1
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git#v29

Updated Procfile:

web: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; gunicorn projectname.wsgi
```

My *settings.py* it's configured:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'django.contrib.gis',
]

default_dburl = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
DATABASES = {
    'default': config('DATABASE_URL', default=default_dburl, cast=dburl),
}
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = config('DB_ENGINE')
```

My DB_ENGINE is at .env file:

`DB_ENGINE=django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis`

References I already read:

[Installing postgis](https://blog.heroku.com/building_location_based_apps_with_postgis)

[Buildpacks](http://samarthbansal.com/2014/06/setting-up-geodjango-on-heroku/)

[Buildpacks 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350422/installing-geodjango-on-heroku)

[Configuring GeoDjango](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis)

I can't figure out solutions,

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend helped me in other forum, he told me to change the buildpack url on heroku to:

```
git://github.com/dulaccc/heroku-buildpack-geodjango.git#1.1
```

And I added this lines to *settings.py*:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = environ.get('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = environ.get('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

It solved the problem to deploy the application.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you were able to figure this out. I am having the same problems on my own heroku instance. Went through the settings that you've added and I still can't seem to get it working. What are the settings you ended up with specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `GDAL` in your heroku instance.

Here is the buildpack for heroku

https://github.com/mojodna/heroku-buildpack-gdal

Comment: Nice, I'll try that now and post results here

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't worked. From an answer of other forum, I solved installing other buildpack (git://github.com/dulaccc/heroku-buildpack-geodjango.git#1.1) and added some scripts in my settings.py. I will create a answer here for that. I appreciated your help.